# systemctl enable differs from systemctl start, how?

Tags: mysql, arch-linux, systemd

I am running an Arch Linux (latest, up-to-date) box, and attempting to get MySQL to start at boot. With the systemd package installed I have systemctl available, and as such I can do things like this:

```
systemctl start mysqld.service
systemctl [stop|status|restart] mysqld.service
```

That's all fine, and works great when I want to start/stop manually, however, when it comes to getting it to start at boot (by using 'enable' on systemctl, I get some nasty output):

```
[root@rudivarch ~]# systemctl enable mysqld.service
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
```

Obviously, since the other commands work just fine, I'm seriously confused by this and have spent a good while trying to figure it out... systemctl status outputs this:

```
[root@rudivarch ~]# systemctl status mysqld.service
mysqld.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/mysqld)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue, 31 Jan 2012 15:32:28 +0000; 1min 25s ago
    Process: 589 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/mysqld stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 257 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/mysqld start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    CGroup: name=systemd:/system/mysqld.service
```

Anybody have any ideas as to why 'enable' doesn't work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`mysqld.service` is a "virtual" unit – it doesn't exist on the filesystem, it's just part of systemd's compatibility layer. You can start it and systemd will run the legacy `/etc/rc.d/mysqld` initscript, but you cannot `systemctl enable` it because you need a real `.service` file which could be symlinked into the proper place.

You can write such a unit yourself and put it in `/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=MySQL Server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
User=mysql
Group=mysql
WorkingDirectory=/usr

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Run `systemctl daemon-reload` after creating/modifying.

---

Alternatively, you can install the `initscripts-systemd` package, which includes `arch-daemons.target` for automatically starting services defined in `rc.conf`. However, this package might go away soon, and it's always better to have native configuration files for the init system in use.

Comment: Thanks! I actually wrote my own mysqld.service that resembles this very closely yesterday, but passes through to /etc/rc.d/mysqld start/stop for ExecStart/ExecStop. Accepted, will post my version up also in case somebody else finds it! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

@Grawity's answer is correct and probably better than this, but I did get it solved yesterday basically by passing through to the rc.d script...

/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service

```
[Unit]
Description=MySQL Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/mysqld start
ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/mysqld stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2):

Nota bene: Remember to put host-specific unit files under `/etc/systemd/system/` and NOT `/lib/systemd/system/`.

The latter is for distro-specific stuff; the former is for host-specific stuff that you configure yourself.  It's like `/usr/bin/` vs. `/usr/local/bin/`, respectively.

So unless a package installs unit files by itself (under `/lib/systemd/system/`), put your own "custom" stuff under `/etc/systemd/system/`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question. This looks more like a comment to @Rudi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Enable is to activate "unit" aka daemon aka service at startup of `systemd`.

OpenSUSE:

```
# systemctl list-units --all | grep sql
mysql.service             loaded inactive dead          LSB: Start the MySQL database 
(good)

# systemctl enable mysql.service
mysql.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig mysql on
insserv: Service localfs has to exists for service vmware-USBArbitrator
insserv: Service network is missed in the runlevels 2 to use service vmware
Warning: unit files do not carry install information. No operation executed.

(it actually redirects to old chkconfig/sysvinit and that corrects init databases)

# systemctl start mysql.service

(no output)

# systemctl status mysql.service
mysql.service - LSB: Start the MySQL database server
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
          Active: active (running) since Tue, 31 Jan 2012 20:07:52 +0100; 5s ago
         Process: 999999 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/mysql.service
                  ├ 999999 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --mysqld=mysqld --user=mysql...
                  └ 999999 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql...

(sort of runs)
```

Comment: Yes I understand this, and mysqld is a daemon/service that I want to run at startup. This is my point, it starts/stops, but won't "enable".

Answer (score 0):

On my FC15 system, when I ran  'systemctl enable mysqld.service', it automagically came back with:

> mysqld.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
>   Executing /sbin/chkconfig mysqld on

So try running:
`/sbin/chkconfig mysqld on`

Answer (score 0):

If you've got ... when enabling your service unit, copy it to /etc/systemd/system

```
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
```

To enable your service unit, add below the ... so you can system enable mysqld.service (its enable in every user's namespace)

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Cheers,
sugatang itlog